# Java, TreeSet. Can we iterate elements from not first element?

Tags: java, time, iterator, treeset

Good day.

I use `TreeSet`, for example `TreeSet<Integer> t`.
And I want to print all numbers from set t between x and y.

```
void print(Integer x,Integer y, TreeSet<Integer> t){
...
}
```

How to do it?
Of Course I can get `t.iterator()`, and iterator all numbers from set and check is it greats x and less y.
Time complexity is y steps.
but if y-x is small. It will be better to get t.higher() and after that iterate the elements in set until it less than y.
This solution can be implemented in C++.
And it's time complexity is `log (t.size())+(y-x)`.

How to do in in Java?

Comment: `t.subSet(x, false, y, false)` if you mean `x < ? < y`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SortedSet` interface (which `TreeSet` implements). For example:

```
SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    set.add(i);
}

int from = 2;
int to = 4;
for (int x : set.subSet(from, to+1)) { // Note that the higher bound is exclusive.
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
```